# Why does $E[R] = E[B]$ for an $M/M/1$ queue?

Tags: queueing-theory

I am preparing for an exam and understand why the mean service time $E[B]$ equals $\frac{1}{\mu}$ for an $M/M/1$ queue but I fail to intuitively understand why the mean remaining service time is the same in this case, i.e $E[R] = E[B]$. Why is this so?

I am also unsure what $E[R]$ and $E[B]$ become when there are more servers, i.e. for an $M/M/2$ or $M/M/3$.

**EDIT**
I am using Kendall notation for my queues: $M/M/2$ means Poisson arrivals,
Poisson service times with 2 servers. $\mu$ is the service rate.

Comment: Okay wait, you are mixing things up a little bit. You know $E[B] =1/\mu$ by integrating the density. But you know that $E[B] =E[R] $ by the memoryless property.

Comment: Correct, thank you! I have edited the question.

Comment: I think you'll need to define your terms more clearly here.  I feel like the answer's not hard, most likely involving something like a Poisson distribution, but your notation - which may even be specific to your textbook or your professor - doesn't 100% convey your meaning.

Comment: You know what the M 's in Kendall's notation stand for?  Memoryless!

Comment: @MarkL.Stone yes I knew that but did not completely grasp how this memorylessness worked, I get that now. Still not sure on what E[B] becomes for more servers though.